# Variant of vertex cover in bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I have this problem, and I am not sure whether it is known.

Given a bipartite graph $G(U, V, E)$.

Define two sets $V_{e}, V_{o} \subseteq V$ such that $V_{e}$ and $V_{o}$ are disjoint.

Now, define another set $C \subseteq U$.

For $v \in V$, let $\Gamma(v)$ be the number of vertices in $C$ adjacent to $v$. Here is the problem:

1. Find $C$ such that $\Gamma(v)$ is odd for all $v \in V_{o}$ and $\Gamma(v)$ is even for all $v \in V_{e}$.
2. Can you find the smallest $C$ (The $C$ with the smallest cardinality).

Does anybody know if this problem is a version of another known problem or how to reduce it to another problem?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: In my opinion the question is very interesting and it would be a shame if it was closed. Add a couple of phrases about where you met this problem and what attempts you made to solve it. I see already three voices demanding to close your question. And note that for a graph $K_{3.3}$ and $|V_0|=1$, $|V_1|=2$ such $C$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

There is the following natural algebraic reformulation of your problem. Let $F=\{0,1\}$ be the two-element field. Put $L=F^U$. Then $L$ is the linear space over $F$.

For each $C\subset U$ let $\overline C\in F^U$ be the characteristic function of the set $C$, that is for each $u\in U$ the $u$-th component of $\bar C$ equals $1$, if $u\in C$, and equals $0$, otherwise. Then the correspondence $C\mapsto \overline C$ is the bijection between the family of all subsets of the set $U$ and the set $F^U$.

For each $v\in V$ let $N(v)$ be the neighborhood of $v$ and $\overline v=\overline{N(v)}$. Then the subset $C$ of $U$ satisfies Condition 1 of the problem iff $(\overline C,\overline v)=0$ for each $v\in V_e$ and  $(\overline C,\overline v)=1$ for each $v\in V_o$. The latter condition is a system of linear equations over the field $F$. Similarly to the case of the field of the real numbers, the system has a solution iff the respective matrices have equal ranks.